# Sqlite in Visual Studio 2008 Smart Device VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, smart-device

im developing a project where i have to read a single database file (.db) from the directory "personal" in a PDA, im using smart device vb.net and i dont know if there's a way to read that single database file, i would post here what i've tried but unfortunately i haven't found anything, if there's a way i would be very happy, thanks!

```
-Visual Studio 2008
 - VIsual Basic SmartDevice
 - Target: Windows Mobile 2003 Pocket PC.
```

In the case that it cant be done, is there a way to read a single database file, i mean, if it can't be done with .db, is there another kind of database file that the program can read just that one, in the directory "\personal\mydatabase.db"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.data.SQLite included a compact framework version

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: How do i use it? i'm lost in this field, sorry.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2013/02/14/sqlite-and-windows-embedded-compact.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to instal SQL CE 3.5 on the device and the sdk on the Computer.
(When you install the sdk, this will create a folder with all the cab files you will need)

You Can Download it Here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12264

Comment: and then i can call it like a namespace and usit right? or how?